# AudioToolbox, C-function pointers, and Swift

Tags: swift, function-pointers, audiotoolbox

I'm working, tentatively, with the `AudioToolbox` API using Swift 2.0 and Xcode 7b6. The API uses a lot of c-language constructs, including function pointers. This is my first time working with commands like `withUnsafeMutablePointer` and `unsafeBitCast`. I am looking for a reality check to make sure that I am not way off base in what I am doing.

For example, to open a file stream, you use the following function:

```
func AudioFileStreamOpen(
      _ inClientData: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>
    , _ inPropertyListenerProc: AudioFileStream_PropertyListenerProc
    , _ inPacketsProc: AudioFileStream_PacketsProc
    , _ inFileTypeHint: AudioFileTypeID
    , _ outAudioFileStream: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioFileStreamID>) -> OSStatus
```

Just the type signature of the function makes me start to sweat.

At any rate, the `inClientData` parameter needs to be an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`, and the pointer will point to an instance of the same class I am working in. In other words, it needs to be a pointer to `self`. My approach is to call the function using `withUnsafeMutablePointer` like this:

```
var proxy = self

let status = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&proxy) {
      AudioFileStreamOpen($0, AudioFileStreamPropertyListener
    , AudioFileStreamPacketsListener, 0, &audioFileStreamID)
    }
```

My first question is whether or not I'm using `withUnsafeMutablePointer` correctly here. I wasn't sure how to get a pointer to `self` - just writing `&self` doesn't work, because `self` is immutable. So I declared `proxy` as a variable and passed a reference to that, instead. I don't know if this will work or not, but it was the best idea I came up with.

Next, `AudioFileStreamPropertyListener` and `AudioFileStreamPacketsListener` are `C` callback functions. They each get passed the pointer to `self` that I created using `withUnsafeMutablePointer` in `AudioFileStreamOpen`. The pointer is passed in as an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`, and I need to cast it back to the type of my class (`AudioFileStream`). To do that, I believe I need to use `unsafeBitCast`. For example, here is `AudioFileStreamPropertyListener`:

```
let AudioFileStreamPropertyListener: AudioFileStream_PropertyListenerProc 
    = { inClientData, inAudioFileStreamID, inPropertyID, ioFlags in

        let audioFileStream = unsafeBitCast(inClientData, AudioFileStream.self)

        audioFileStream.didChangeProperty(inPropertyID, flags: ioFlags)
}
```

That compiles fine, but again I'm not sure if I'm using `unsafeBitCast` correctly, or if that is even the correct function to be using in this kind of situation. So, is `unsafeBitCast` the correct way to take an `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>` and cast it to a type that you can actually use inside of a `C` function pointer?

Comment: This is a bit off-topic for an answer, but I think it would be a fun exercise to try and wrap these nasty old C APIs in some Swift classes that make it much easier to use :)

Comment: Agreed. If I can figure out the basics, that may be the end result :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting that the `inClientData` "context" param is bridged as `UnsafeMutablePointer`, since I doubt the AudioToolbox APIs will modify your data. It seems it would be more appropriate if they'd used `COpaquePointer`. Might want to [file a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com).

I think your use of `withUnsafeMutablePointer` is wrong. The pointer (`$0`) will be the address of **the variable `proxy`**, not the address of your instance. (You could say `$0.memory = [a new instance]` to change it out for a different instance, for example. This is a bit confusing because its type is `UnsafeMutablePointer<MyClass>` — and in Swift, the class type is itself a pointer/reference type.)

I was going to recommend you use Unmanaged / COpaquePointer, but I tested it, and realized this does exactly the same thing as `unsafeAddressOf(self)`!

These are equivalent:

```
let data = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
let data = unsafeAddressOf(self)
```

And these are equivalent:

```
let obj = Unmanaged<MyClass>.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(data)).takeUnretainedValue()
let obj = unsafeBitCast(data, MyClass.self)
```

While the `Unmanaged` approach makes logical sense, I think you can see why it might be prefereable to use `unsafeAddressOf`/`unsafeBitCast` :-)

Or, you might consider an extension on Unmanaged for your own convenience:

```
extension Unmanaged
{
    func toVoidPointer() -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> {
        return UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(toOpaque())
    }
    static func fromVoidPointer(value: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) -> Unmanaged<Instance> {
        return fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(value))
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
let data = Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toVoidPointer()
let obj = Unmanaged<MyClass>.fromVoidPointer(data).takeUnretainedValue()
```

Of course, you will need to ensure that your object is being retained for the duration that you expect it to be valid in callbacks. You could use `passRetained`, but I would recommend having your top-level controller hold onto it.

See some related discussion at https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5134#15725.

Comment: Thank you. Does this seem right? `var ptr = unsafeAddressOf(self); let status = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&ptr) { ... }`

Comment: Nope; you should just pass `ptr` directly in for `inClientData`.

Comment: Doesn't work... `ptr` is an `UnsafePointer<Void>`, not `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>`. The function won't take it...

Comment: Ah, well you can freely convert between those (e.g. `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>(unsafeAddressOf(self))`). Or use one of my other approaches from the answer above.

Comment: @RomanSausarnes I also just came across this post which might be helpful: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/5134#15725